# RewriteRule File Directory in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php file inside folder of the website. For example, the file path is https://example.com/admin/login.php

Then I want to put in htaccess with following code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ admin/login.php [L]
```

Unfortunately, it's not work. I tried to search and read many tutorial but it still doesn't work too. Is anybody know what I have to write the htaccess? Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

Move the "login" rule up before the "index" rule that catches everything.

Comment: Comment line with "RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]" or leave only "RewriteEngine on" and "RewriteRule ^login$ admin/login.php [L]" for testing